# QT 5.7 linux 32 bit download

Tags: qt5, qt5.7

I have linux ubuntu 12.04 32bit version installed on my system. I wanted to installed QT 5.7. But I am not able to find any download link for linux 32 bit version of QT5.7. 
Where can I find QT5.7 32bit download?

Comment: Have you tried the [http://download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/qt-unified-linux-x86-online.run](online installer)?

Comment: looks like you will have to compile

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Qt 5.6.0, pre-built binaries for Linux 32bit is not provided anymore. You need to compile it yourself.

Source: https://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/02/23/qt-5-6-0-release-candidate-available/#comment-1197215